# What do all the pictures on the front of the "Unix and Linux System Administration Handbook" represent?

Tags: linux, history, books

I'm a newcomer to Unix and Linux, and I've been trying to get up to speed on everything. One of the guides I've used is the "Unix and Linux System Administration Handbook"

It's a pretty great book, and I'm enjoying reading through it, but I'm really confused by all the things that are on the cover. While this may not be a typical question for Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, I don't think it is necessarily a bad question so I'm going to go out on a limb and ask:

```
What do all the crazy things on the cover of this book represent?
```

Attached is an image of the book and a reference key. Thanks for the history lesson.

[image: unix-administration-handbook.jpg]

1. Flag
2. Flag (Finland's for Linus Torvalds?)
3. Bird / Cake
4. Guy in a lab coat with a baseball bat
5. Gnome
6. Clam
7. Python
8. Cowboy and two cats
9. Penguin
10. Gorilla
11. Old dude on another boat sailing away and apparently flipping off this boat
12. Two guys carved in wood with a shield
13. Octopus / Monster
14. Filing cabinet
15. Clock
16. Indian
17. Girl with a book
18. Computer using a canon
19. Window frame
20. Lady, fishing pole, and boot
21. Apple Core
22. Less and More
23. Bar of Soap / Can of Spam
24. Periscope
25. Heart / Valentine
26. Monster with Maracas

ps: What is the significance of the ship?

Comment: The ship is presumably Evi's yacht, Wonderland. She makes international sailing journeys.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate! The cover art was completely redrawn and the "duplicate" question is regarding the old cover.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The artist [Lisa Haney](http://lisahaneyillustration.blogspot.com/2011/09/i-was-asked-by-few-people-to-explain.html) has provided an explanation on her blog. [Click through because the back cover has more...]

Some of the more colourful include:

6  Bash and Perl & Shell
9  The Linux penguin forcing the Windows gorilla to walk the plank
11 [Evi Nemeth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evi_Nemeth) makes gesture