# What are all the items on the cover of the "Linux Administration Handbook"?

Tags: linux, history, books

As I mentioned in [What do all the pictures on the front of the "Unix and Linux System Administration Handbook" represent?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26045/) I'm fairly new to Linux and Unix.

@jasonwryan provided an excellent link to a blog that describes all of the items on the front of the first book, but is there an explanation available for all the items on the cover of the the "Linux Administration Handbook"? I didn't see any other entries on Lisa Hanley's blog.

[image: Cover]

1. Cloud
2. Penguin Skiing
3. VISTA Helicopter
4. Tombstone
5. Coffin
6. Book
7. Dead Cat
8. Boy in a cube
9. Monkey on a vine
10. Tire
11. Restrained Spider
12. Cliff
13. Spock
14. Hand
15. Doctor
16. Tunnel

Comment: This isn't going to be a recurring thing, is it? I left the first one even though I think it's probably off-topic, but if you have a dozen books on your bookshelf you're planning to ask about I'll reconsider

Comment: Just these two books, thanks for your help

Comment: Note the _first_ [edition detail](http://oscarbonilla.com/tag/unix/) @4 "R.I.P. [Biff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biff)" and @8 rat bearing mention [sssca](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_Broadband_and_Digital_Television_Promotion_Act).

Answer (score 5):

1. [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6), a cloud looming over the horizon. At the time, IPv6 was a scary beast whose widespread adoption was thought to be in the near future. Now, IPv6 is a scary beast whose widespread adoption is thought to be in the near future.
2. While this may look like a [penguin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) from afar, I believe this is [Duke, the mascot of Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duke_%28mascot%29#Mascot).
3. [Windows Vista](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista), not part of the scenery on the ground but something you have to cope with.
4. 10 MB/s [Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet) was common, but by the time this edition came out, [10BASE5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10BASE5) and [10BASE2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10BASE2) had been almost completely wiped out by cheap 100MB/s [Cat-5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable) with [RJ-45](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8P8C#8P8C) connectors (yes, that's how everybody calls it).
5. [UUCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUCP) is dead and buried. What's UUCP? A protocol for machine-to-machine transfers, from the days when intermittent connectivity was the norm.
6. "LAH" — refers to original Linux Administration Handbook
7. Looks like a raccoon, which is the emblem of [MINIX 3](http://www.minix3.org/), released with [*Operating Systems Design and Implementation 3rd edition*](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/academic/product/0,,0131429388,00%2ben-USS_01DBC.html). For a history of the strained relations between Linux's creator and [MINIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MINIX)'s creator, read about the [Tanenbaum–Torvalds debate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanenbaum%E2%80%93Torvalds_debate).
8. [ITIL](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Information_Technology_Infrastructure_Library) is a methodology for managing IT systems. Some think it puts sysadmins in a box.
9. ?
10. ?
11. I presume the spider web represents the [World Wide Web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web). A lot of people use the web to make money (hence the `$` eyes), and security for the web is a common task for Linux systems (hence the chain and padlock).
12. ?
13. [Alien](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_%28software%29), a tool to convert software packages.
14. The [finger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_protocol) daemon.
15. The [SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) daemon, a system diagnosis tool (many devices and daemons report their status and can sometimes be configured through SNMP).

Comment: Thank you!! added a link to a higher res cover: http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/6169/coveral.jpg

Answer (score 2):

I'll bite on the first three, front row and center.

1) Web Spider (probably a rogue one that doesn't respect robots.txt, got caught stealing server resources and so has been locked out)

2) Daemon (any background server process)

3) Finger Daemon (an early rudimentary identification server that allowed you to query it to find out about people on the system) Giving "The Universal American Symbol of Defiance" as its usefulness degraded over time and people started abusing it.  Finger Daemon also demonstrates that computers operate on a digital binary system. Clenched fist = 0, Middle finger erect = 1. Just remember that the next time your system is giving you the Digital One. If it was British, a trinary system would be required to offer the same response.

Comment: ps: i added numbers to the book cover since you posted